# JQuery tablesorter : No table, thead, tbody or tablesorter has already been

Tags: tablesorter

I have this simple html page with a sortable table. I'm using TableSorter 2.17.8 min

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/rules.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="rulesTable" class="tablesorter">
<tr>
.....
```

My rules.js has

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#rulesTable").tablesorter({
        widthFixed : true,
        showProcessing: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders'],
        debug: true,
        theme: 'blue'
    });
});
```

But i keep getting this error when i load the page

```
ERROR: stopping initialization! No table, thead, tbody or tablesorter has already been initialized jquery.tablesorter.min.js:5d jquery.tablesorter.min.js:5g.setup jquery.tablesorter.min.js:5(anonymous function) jquery.tablesorter.min.js:5n.extend.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2g.construct jquery.tablesorter.min.js:5(anonymous function) rules.js:4j jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2k.fireWith jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2n.extend.ready jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2I jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted it doesn't appear that you have a thead or tbody, and that would cause the plugin to error because it needs those tags.
Should look like:

```
<table id="rulesTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If that doesn't work try moving the plugin path to a more simple location just to make sure it is able to reach it fine.